# Set of variables

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that a *set* is a collection of distinct objects. Let's say I have a data set $\mathcal{D}=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$, is it the variables or the objects they are representing that has to be distinct?

For example if $x_1=1$ and $x_2=1$, will both $x_1$ and $x_2$ be in the set?

Comment: Yes.  Your set will consist of $\{1, x_3, \dotsc, x_n\}$.  That being said, a set is probably not a good model for a collection of data.  A tuple (an $n$-dimensional ordered object, like a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$) might be a more appropriate object to work with.

Comment: You seem to be asking with some purpose in mind. It's hard to say what exactly you are looking for. Mathematics is usually extensional, so if two things are the same, then they are the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I ask because I have a data set of observations which may contain duplicates, and wonder whether I can denote it as a set. I have seen people do so in the literature.

Comment: If you have some observations, then they were made in some order in time, hence you have a (finite) _sequence_ of values observed/measured. And a sequence is a function from natural numbers to some results' space, which may well assign same value to many different arguments (consider a constant function...) Or the observations may have been made in some enumerated places, or conditions – then you probably have a _vector_ of observed values.

Answer (score 2):

If $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = 1$, then $x_1 = x_2$.

When two things are equal, then any question you can ask will have the same answer for both things.

Often, we conceive this as the strings of symbols "$x_1$" and "$x_2$" being two different *names* for the *same* mathematical object. As another example, in integer arithmetic, "$1+2$" and "$3$" are two different names for the same number.

---

The point of saying a set is a collection of *distinct* objects is to contrast with another notion called a *multiset*.

If $\mathcal{B}$ is a *multiset*, it makes sense to ask "How many times does  $z$ appear in $\mathcal{B}$?"

But if $\mathcal{D}$ is a *set*, the only thing that makes sense to ask is "Does $z$ appear in $\mathcal{D}$?"

Put another way, the sets $\{ 1, 1, 2, 3 \}$ and $\{ 1, 2, 3 \}$ are equal. And they are both equal to the set $\{ 3,1,2,3,2,2,1,3 \}$ as well.

Comment: Thanks! I guess sets are used sloppy in some fields of science. To claim that I have a set $\mathcal{D}=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ of length $n$ seems risky, since I don't know if there are duplicates.

Comment: @Roland: Sometimes people even say "set" when they care about the *ordering* of the elements too! It boils down to the fact there is an English word "set" as well as a mathematical term "set". You can't always assume the mathematical term is meant.